# HIVE SQL where clause not working as expected

Tags: sql, hive

I have a where clause where I only want to return records where field1 contains "*F*" but it's picking any value which contains "F" does the "_" not get looked at?

Eg.
Field1
JBHi-Fi
JBHIFI_F_1234

```
select * from table1
where field1 like "%_F_%"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_` is considered as wild card like `%` and it means search for 1 character. So, your query is as good as `'%F%'`. If you want to search for a pattern like `%_F_%'` then you need to use this \ as escape character.
Use

```
where field1 like "%\_F\_%"
```